# Consuming WCF service in MVVM application

Tags: wcf, design-patterns, mvvm, viewmodel, dto

In my client application I have a View, ViewModel and a Service Layer DTO as my Model.

My issue is this particular view must also consume a whole bunch of other services in order to populate some drop down lists, so now my ViewModel has references to multiple DTOs. Is this good practice? or should the WCF return a single DTO that contains everything the ViewModel needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine, as ViewModel is just another abstraction. It's a Model for a certain View and can be composed from multiple DTOs.

The ViewModel's task is to prepare the data to be displayed by the View, so if composition of multiple DTOs is necessary to be consumed and displayed by the View, then it's okay to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! A slightly different question what is the best way to consume the service? By injecting the services into the ViewModel Constructor?

Comment: Yep. Injecting it into the ViewModel is the common practice, and pretty easy too with an IoC container